# Generic class method on non-generic class

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, generics, type-hinting

I am trying to create a method on a non-generic class which creates another, generic class and returns it.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

@dataclass
class Item(Generic[T]):
    name: str
    value: T = None

class OtherClass:
    def CreateItem(self, type: T, name: str, value=None):
        return Item[T](name=name, value=value)

other = OtherClass()
item = other.CreateItem[int]("some_field", 45)
```

Where `item` in the end should be a `Item[int]`. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost works. You can fix it by passing the type `int` as an argument to the `CreateItem` function:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

@dataclass
class Item(Generic[T]):
    name: str
    value: T = None

class OtherClass:
    def CreateItem(self, tp, name: str, value=None):
        return Item[tp](name=name, value=value)

other = OtherClass()
item = other.CreateItem(int, "some_field", 45)
```

However, note that type hints in Python are mostly used for static analysis in type checkers like mypy and IDEs. They are usually not used at runtime.

You could also replace `OtherClass` by this, without using the specific type hint of `Item`:

```
class OtherClass2:
    def CreateItem(self, name: str, value=None):
        return Item(name=name, value=value)

other2 = OtherClass2()
item2 = other2.CreateItem("some_field", 45)
```

There will be no difference between `item` and `item2`:

```
assert item == item2  # this assertion will pass
```

Comment: How is this different from doing ``Item[Any]``? To my understanding the type for item or item2 will have to be inferred, and is not enforceable by the type checker.